# Will a GFCI-protected 15A circuit meet light power tool needs in a shed?

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci, shed

I want to run electric from my house to shed, which is 23 feet from my house. I was going to run 12/2 wire from the outside gfci underground to the shed. I plan on having 2 lights and 4 outlets in the shed. The outside gfci breaker is 15amp. Will I run into any problems if I occasionally run a power tool with the shed lights on and possibly a stereo? I don’t have a workshop in my shed or anything. My only other option was to run a dedicated line to my electrical panel. If I did this, what amp breaker would I put in for the shed that’s compatible/suitable for 12/2 600 volt wire?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run a direct bury cable instead of a conduit?  Also, how much further is the panel away from the shed?

Comment: I’m running pvc conduit with either scenario. I’m trying to determine the easiest way to wire my shed from the house. I suspect, using the existing outdoor gfci would be easiest. It has the 15 amp breaker. If I went directly from the shed to the panel on the back of the house and added a new breaker, what are my options; or what’s the recommended breaker for 12/2 wire? 20 amp? Distance from shed to panel, and shed to existing outdoor gfci are negligible.

Comment: It’ll run a saw. It’ll run a dust collector. Not both at once though.

Answer (score 5):

### If you're running PVC anyway...there's no need to wrestle that UF alligator down the pipe!

Since you're planning to run PVC conduit in any case, you shouldn't bother trying to wrestle that 12/2 UF alligator down it.  Instead, what you want to run inside the conduit are 3 individual 12AWG THHN/THWN *wires* (hot, neutral, ground) of the appropriate colors. This takes up far less room in the conduit, is far easier to pull down the conduit, and lets you use *stranded* wire, which also makes your life easier pulling things.

### Running a fat conduit is a wise investment

Furthermore, if I were in your shoes, I'd make that conduit *fat*, so that the next person (who may be you!) doesn't have to dig it up and replace it if they need more power at the shed.  A 1" conduit will easily accommodate a 60A feeder, so it'd be my minimum size for this; if possible, I'd go up to 1.5", which provides enough room for a 125A(!) feeder to the shed in the future, if such is desired.

### Having GFCI upstream of outbuildings is never a good idea

However, there's no reason to provide GFCI upstream of an outbuilding, and a couple good reasons *not* to, primarily that you really do not want your lights knocked out from under you when something like a faulty power tool trips a GFCI.  As a result, running from your panel with a conventional breaker at the panel and a GFCI receptacle in the shed is the best plan; it also works well with the fat conduit mentioned above.  It does mean you'll need to make sure there's 18" of dirt between the top of the conduit and the finished grade once you've backfilled the trench, though; in order to do this, you'll need to trench down to 21 or 22".

Comment: Given the short distance Rigid is worth considering; only need 6” cover for that. Hella expensive but trench it with a garden trowel lol...

Answer (score 2):

Your dedicated run of 12/2 could handle a maximum breaker size of 20 amps and you'd need GFCI protection in the shed. If the wire size for your existing GFCI is 14/2 then the maximum breaker size is 15 Amps even if you run 12/2 to the shed from that GFCI. A small power tool, lights and a stereo shouldn't be a problem if the existing circuit was lightly loaded and wouldn't be a problem with a dedicated one.

Comment: If I end up going the existing outdoor gfci route, is 12/2 better than 14/2, or is there any advantage in either case in this scenario? They’re only a few dollars in price. Not sure if there’s an advantage in performance or reliability? I’m a novice with electrical work. Sorry, if it’s a stupid question.

Comment: There's no advantage to running #12 over #14 except that if you decide later to make it a 20 Amp dedicated circuit, the #12 is already there.  You really ought to think about making it a dedicated circuit. With a conduit run the whole way you could upgrade in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I’m considering going straight to the panel with the 12/2 and putting in a dedicated 20 amp breaker. I watched a video on it. Didn’t seem too complicated. Just need to make sure the main breaker is off. Ground to neutral bus, negative to neutral bus, and then hot or positive to circuit breaker.

Comment: You'll be running 3-#12 AWG THHN,  not the 12/2 NB cable.